# Probability a function has real zeros

Tags: probability

What is the probability that the function *f(x)* = *x*^2 + *rx* + *s* has real zeros when *r* and *s* are real numbers between 0 and 9 inclusive?

Comment: graph $r^2-4s\geq0$ on $[0,9]\times[0,9]$, take the ratio of the appropriate areas

Answer (score 3):

In order to have real roots, the discriminant has to be nonnegative:
$$r^2-4s\ge0\,$$
So, draw the $s=r^2/4$ parabole in the $r,s$-coordinate plane within the $[0,9]\times[0,9]$ square, and find the area of the region $s\le r^2/4$. (This is basically, an integral.) Divide it by $81$.